# C# Nuget References

Tags: xamarin, dll, nuget

I'm a bit confused about the dlls that are installed when using Nuget to install libraries to my Xamarin Projects. I mainly manage the nugets for the whole solution. So when i install a nuget i choose all platform projects as targets, meaning the PCL, the Android and the iOS Project. In most cases there are different dlls, like #.XForms, #.XForms.Android and #.Android, for example in the Community Toolkit ([FormsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit)), which is also available from Nuget.

In my understanding the .Android dlls need to be used in the android platform project, and the XForms dll without android should be used in the PCL. A good example is the Converters.dll. That's code only used in the pcl, but the dll is also automatically referenced in the platform projects. So my question is, why is this the case?
I see this behavior not only for this toolkit but also for other apis, like Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

PCL dlls will contain codes that accessing common API for the targeted PCL profiles. For the UI project (Android and iOS) need to be using different dlls most of the time because it need to access to platform specific APIs. For example, API to check network connection is different in iOS and Android.

But you should not be worry about which dlls to use. NuGet package manager already handle which dlls to be use in the solutions. So, you will just need to include the packages and let the package manager to handle the rest of it.

Comment: Yeah, i understand that there is platform specific code in the platform dlls, to be accessed by me directly in the platform specific project and i guess also for the libraries PCL dll, to access platform functions (A Custom Renderer for a custom View in the librarie for example). I also understand that there is a PCL dll to be accessed from my pcl project. But my questions was, why is the PCL dll also referenced in the platform project? I deleted it for testing purposes and the librarie stuff i use still works as expected. I'm trying to understand the concept, thats why i'm asking. Thx anyways

Comment: The packages that use in PCL need to be also include in platform project. Without including it, your app will still able to build. However, during runtime, it will not able to find the assembly and will result in crash.

Comment: But why is this the case? I build a little library myself with just a ValueConverter in it. Obviously the ValueConverter is only used in the pcl project, for some value convertions on bindings. Why should this PCL dll need a reference in the platform project? I think it was working fine if only referenced in PCL project. Same should be correct for the PCL dlls of several extern libraries, shouldn't it?